# automator take screenshots of website recursively

Tags: macos, automator

I would like to use Automator to:

1- extract URLs from a text file with about 50 URLs
2- open it in firefox
3- take a screenshot of the window
4- Close the window
5- do it a again for the next 49 URLs.

> First step, I can't extract urls from the text files, automator give
>   me nothing when I do it.

Well, this is done know, mistake from me I had to use get content of text edit document before extract url.

> Second thing, I don't know how to make it recursively URL after URL.

Know it opens all urls at the same time in different tabs, which make my firefox to shut down because of the number of tab open at the same time.
How could I make it do it url after url ?

It's the first time I use Automator and I don't know nothing about apple scripting.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

No need for Automator, just use `webkit2png` which you can install easily with `homebrew` like this:

```
brew install webkit2png
```

Then put a list of all your sites in a file called `sites.txt` that looks like this:

```
http://www.google.com
http://www.ibm.com
```

and then run `webkit2png` like this:

```
webkit2png - < sites.txt
```

Or, if you don't like that approach, you can do something like this just with the built-in tools in OS X. Save the following in a text file called `GrabThem`

```
#!/bin/bash
while read f
do
   echo Processing $f...
   open "$f"
   sleep 3
   screencapture ${i}.png
   ((i++))
done < sites.txt
```

Then make it executable in Terminal (you only need do this once) with

```
chmod +x GrabThem
```

Then run it like this in Terminal:

```
./GrabThem
```

and the files will be called `1.png`, `2.png` etc.

You can see the newest files at the bottom of the list is you run:

```
ls -lrt
```

You may want to look at the options for `screencapture`, maybe the ones for selecting a specific window rather than the whole screen. You can look at the options by typing:

```
man screencapture
```

and hitting `SPACE` to go forwards a page and `q` to quit.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not very comfortable with the terminal. For the first tip: I need to use it with firefox (except if you know a way to change every font in every website with safari, but i didn't find anything like this). For the second, and excuse-me if I look stupid saying this but, where should I save the Grabthem file and the sites.txt file? Should I write the whole path in the terminal to make it work?
Thank you for your help.